# Redirect old domain url with .html extension to subdomain

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

Hi would like to redirect with `.htaccess` all URLs that end with `.html` to subdomains like

- `http://example.com/video.html`
- `http://example.com/gallery/first-galery.html`
- `http://example.com/category/month/12/news.html`

to

- `http://archive.example.com/video.html`
- `http://archive.example.com/gallery/first-galery.html`
- `http://archive.example.com/category/month/12/news.html`

On the new site, I have installed WordPress and I want to process all HTTP requests since the old site didn't use HTTPS ad it would be good to avoid collision WP.

Comment: "all HTTP requests since the old site didn't use HTTPS ad it would be good to avoid collision WP" - Although presumably the check for the `.html` extension already avoids the name "collision". These URLs are presumably accessible over HTTPS as well and browsers are starting to default to HTTPS these days (at least it is optional), so if you redirected HTTP-only then some requests won't be redirected that should be. (?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This really depends on the web server you are using. 2 popular web servers are Apache and Nginx.

If you are using Apache, you can create `.htaccess` file in the root directory with the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ http://archive.example.com/$1.html [R=301,L]
```

If you are using Nginx, you need to update the configuration file to include the following:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    rewrite ^/(.*)\.html$ http://archive.example.com/$1.html permanent;
}
```

As you can see, we are using 301 redirect in Apache and `permanent` in Nginx because they are final.

You will also need to have a DNS record set up for the archive.example.com subdomain